# Click "Cancel" on windows security pop up when automating web page from VBA

Tags: vba, web, automation

I have a slight issue.  Randomly, every few iterations of a loop that I use to load information from a web page will pop up a "Windows Security" window that requests my login and password for the page and halts execution of the code.  If I click "Cancel" the macro continues and the information on the page continues to load.  The site is an internal page, and we have already logged in, and whether I enter credentials and check the "remember password" checkbox or click cancel, I get the proper information all the same.

I need a way to grab the pop up when it appears and click cancel programatically, if possible.  One thing I'm having difficulty with is if the pop up is coming from the IE browser or if it is coming from some other programing in windows.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since the pop-up is coming from the browser, you can close it using `SendKeys` (see the [MSDN SendKeys Method Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943%28v=office.10%29.aspx))

For example, to send a tab, followed by a 1-second pause and an enter (which would usually cancel a prompt), you'd do the following :

```
SendKeys "{Tab}"
Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
SendKeys "{Enter}"
```